# PHP regex - pattern does not match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to replace all body and html selectors with a custom class. (Later on the html content will be displayed in a custom container and available css should not effect the main Site.)

Here is a what I've tried:

```
$data = "html body { color: red; }\nbody html { color: red; }\nhtml, body { color: red; }\nbody, html, .body table, #html-TemplateContainer {\nbackground-color:#eee;\n}";
echo "<pre>".preg_replace('/(^|[,}\s]+)(body html|html body|html|body)([,.{\s]*)/is', '$1'.'.foo'.'$3', $data)."</pre>";
```

Which prints:

```
.foo { color: red; }
.foo { color: red; }
.foo, body { color: red; }
.foo, html, .body table, #html-TemplateContainer {
background-color:#eee;
}
```

I do not understand why in line 3 and 4 the body and html (scnd selector) is not replaced, for my understanding it should match the regex?!

Comment: **Don't** use regular expressions to deal with HTML and CSS, use HTML parsers instead.

Comment: Matches can't overlap in your replacements, so in line 3 it matches `html, ` (including the end space) and then cannot match `body`.

Comment: Can you suggest a html-parser which fits for my needs?
I already use csstidy for easier handling but it is not able to simply replace a selector with another.
I also tried Sabberworm but was not able to get it to wrok because of the Namespaces :(

@cbuckley ah .. thanks I got it .. will lookahead work? Ill try ..

Comment: yeah got it, working regex is: `'/(?<=^|[,}\s])(body html|html body|html|body)(?=[,.{\s])/is'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to cbuckley, i had to use lookahead and lookbehind and now it works fine ;)
I made some improvements so it may match now any possibilities.

working code:

```
$data = "html body { color: red; }\nhtml *.class { color: red; }\nhtml,body { color: red; }\nhtml[dir=\"rtl\"], body, .body table, #html-container\n{\n    background-color:#eee;\n}";
echo "<pre>".preg_replace('/(?<=^|[,}\]\s])(\*\s+html\s+body|\*\s+body\s+html|html\s+\*\s+body|html\s+body\s+\*|body\s+\*\s+html|body\s+html\s+\*|\*\s+html|\*\s+body|html\s+\*|html\s+body|body\s+\*|body\s+html|\*|html|body)(?=[,.{\[\s]|$)/is', '.foo', $data)."</pre>";
```

original css:

```
html body { color: red; }
html *.class { color: red; }
html,body { color: red; }
html[dir="rtl"], body, .body table, #html-container
{
    background-color:#eee;
}
```

modified css:

```
.foo { color: red; }
.foo.class { color: red; }
.foo,.foo { color: red; }
.foo[dir="rtl"], .foo, .body table, #html-container
{
    background-color:#eee;
}
```

Multiple occurrence of the same selector can be filtered out afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
 You should try this...
 =========================>


  echo  "<pre>".preg_replace('/(^|#|.|\s]+)(body html|html body|html|body)([^,.{\s]*)/is', 
  '$1'.'.foo'.'$3', $data)."</pre>";
```